# ArcGIS report generation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, reports

I am new to generating reports using ArcGIS Pro (and ArcMap). I wanted to try it out to see if it could be a useful tool for my organization. We use Field Maps to conduct field inspections of certain sites, some the data includes location, deficiency type, X, Y, and text comments describing any issues. I am running into an issue with the text comments. It seems that no matter what I try the report wont wrap the text and the majority of it gets cut off.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the text field box taller on the report designer screen.  In ArcMap, word wrap is the default, but you still have to give the report the space. You could also set the font smaller on this screen. (Sorry, cannot screenshot and share my data.)

In most report design tools, when you make one field taller, you can also set some option (e.g. "CanShrink" in Access) to allow the lines to shrink if the text in the taller field does not need to fill the box you drew for it.

I would try ArcGIS Pro, even though I have not done this yet in that application , because ArcMap's report writer is not very flexible.

Comment: I am actually using arcpro, I did try widening the area and all it did was make the colored area larger but made no change to the text

Comment: I have been working on some similar reports recently in Arc Pro, and I think this answer is about as good as it gets. You need to make the "Details" box larger as well as the individual "Details Field Value Text" box (you can select them in the drawing order pane/contents pane for the report).

The issue is that if you make the Details pane wider, you are effectively widening all of your rows to be twice as big. I have not found any way to shrink the ones with less text. 

Better off just doing this in Excel if you can export it there.